# Can't read property of undefined, even if I have already initialised it. (ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I was making filters with 3 categories, So I designed a Model:

```
export class filtersApplied {    
    public subjects: string[] = [];
    public price: string[] = [];
    public ratings: number[] = [];
 }
```

As soon as a user apply filters from any of these categories, I want all those chosen values to be added into respective array of the model. Lets say I chose "ENGLISH", "MATHEMATICS", and "SCIENCE", So
I want to insert them in "filtersApplied.subjects" so that they can be processed at backend.

allFiltersApplied is a variable which is of type filtersApplied
allFiltersApplied: filtersApplied;

```
 <ul class="filter-category-list">
                <li>
                    <label class="filters-label">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="filter-input"
                value="English"
                (change)="searchBySubject($event)"
              />English
              <span class="filter-num">(123)</span>
            </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="filters-label">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="filter-input"
                value="Physics"
                (change)="searchBySubject($event)"
              />Physics
              <span class="filter-num">(123)</span>
            </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="filters-label">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="filter-input"
                value="Chemistry"
                (change)="searchBySubject($event)"
              />Chemistry
              <span class="filter-num">(123)</span>
            </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="filters-label">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="filter-input"
                value="Mathematics"
                (change)="searchBySubject($event)"
              />Mathematics
              <span class="filter-num">(123)</span>
            </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="filters-label">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                class="filter-input"
                value="Science"
                (change)="searchBySubject($event)"
              />Science
              <span class="filter-num">(123)</span>
            </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

This is my function in ts file:

```
 searchBySubject($event) {
        var subject = $event.target.value;
        console.log(subject); //1
        console.log(this.allFiltersApplied); //2
        console.log(this.allFiltersApplied.subjects); //3
      }
```

The output I got for console.log(this.allFiltersApplied) is undefined;
The output I got for console.log(this.allFiltersApplied.subjects) is Cannot read property 'subjects' of undefined at SearchResultsComponent.searchBySubject;


**My Questions are:** 
1. Why it is showing undefined
2. Why cant read subjects if its already there. I cant even push any value like this.allFiltersApplied.subjects.push("ENGLISH");

**Please Help me in this, I am not getting, why is it behaving like this**

Comment: You did not post enough code for anybody to help.

Comment: @Pointy I have added some HTML also, would u plz review it now

Comment: What is the value of `this`?  Clearly `this.allFiltersApplied` is `undefined`, so probably `this` is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: Sir, I am not much experienced with Angular, but with due respect I think you are also not much experienced

Comment: Well perhaps a `console.log(this)` would help, so that you could at least verify the value.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for consideration, but "this" is written just to access the "allFiltersApplied" variable.

Comment: Exactly. So if `this` is a reference to an object that does not have an "allFiltersApplied" property, then `this.allFiltersApplied` would be `undefined`.  That's why I suggested that you log the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You're stating that `allFiltersApplied` is a variable, but I'm assuming you mean that it's a property of some class. (A variable would be declared with `const`, `let`, or, back in the beforetimes, `var`.)

Assuming you've declared it in some class like so:

```js
export class MyClass {
  allFiltersApplied: filtersApplied;
}
```

you've only declared it, you haven't initialized it, so its value will be `undefined`.

Declaring it as a particular type simply ensures that, when it *is* used, it's used within the constraints of its declared type.

So if you want it to start out with the basic structure of `filtersApplied`, with arrays that can have values pushed into them, you need to initialize it also. Since `filtersApplied` is defined as a `class` rather than a `type`, you'd instantiate it like so:

```js
export class MyClass {
  allFiltersApplied: filtersApplied = new filtersApplied();
}
```

If, however, you defined it as just a `type` (just to enforce its typings) rather than a full `class`, you could initialize your property like so:

```js
export class MyClass {
  allFiltersApplied: filtersApplied = {
    subjects: [],
    price: [],
    ratings: []
  };
}
```

A couple parting notes:

1. The convention for classes and types is that they be UpperCamelCase, so `filtersApplied` should probably be `FiltersApplied` if you wanted to follow convention.
2. Comments like "Sir, I am not much experienced with Angular, but with due respect I think you are also not much experienced" directed at people who are taking the time to try to help you like @Pointy (whose reputation is over 358,000 at the time of this writing, by the way) will likely discourage others from attempting to help you.